# I need help finding Training for CiviCRM

Tags: training

I am looking for just training on how to use CiviCRM.  I am struggling finding anyone that is willing to just do training. Everyone wants to have us sign up for a year contracting committment.  I do not have that in my budget unfortunately as before I became the Executive Director the organization rehauled our website and committed to a relationship with an organization that does not have training available unfortunately.

Comment: Hi! What system are you using attached to Civi (Drupal, WordPress, etc)? I'd be happy to help out with some training.

Comment: Dear Betty, sorry that you cannot find anyone to do just training - that suprises me as well. I am sure you will find someone in the partners directory. If you are open to an online remote training we (SYSTOPIA) would be happy to support you - just drop us a line.

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Some of us are very happy to provide training without an ongoing commitment.  Where are you based?  See [the partner listing](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country_id=&custom_181=All&custom_157=Training&cms=All)

Comment: We are on Drupal 9.  and absolutely we would be open to remote online training

Comment: We are based in Denver, CO